# search:search() vs cts:search() in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I have read about `cts:search()` and `search:search()` separately but could not figure out the exact difference between them. It says `cts:search()` ultimately uses `search:search()`.
Can anyone illustrate in detail the scenario where one should go for `cts:search()` and for `search:search()`.This is not in relation to some particular project work where I need to implement this but in general.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also worth mentioning are the:

- [Client REST API](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/client), which basically exposes the Search API as an HTTP interface
- [Java Client API](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java), which exposes the Client REST API as a set of convenient Java objects, and methods
- [Node.js Client API](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev), which exposes the Client REST API as a set of convenient Node.js objects, and methods

HTH!

Answer (score 15):

The Search API (e.g. `search:search()`) is an XQuery library that provides a high-level interface for some of the core capabilities of MarkLogic, such as search, facets, and aggregates. It uses the lower-level `cts:*` (and other) libraries under the covers, but will save most developers a bunch of typing and debugging.

In general, I'd recommend starting with the Search API. We've put a lot of effort into making sure it's robust and fast. For example, when doing faceted search, it orchestrates getting the search results and calculating facets from range indexes in parallel. There are many other examples of conveniences and best practices that you get out-of-the-box with the Search API. If you need to do something more or different than the Search API provides, there are several places that allow you to work with lower-level `cts:query` instances. For example, `search:resolve()` takes a `cts:query` and calls the equivalent of `search:search()`.

Also, for those working in [Server-Side JavaScript](http://developer.marklogic.com/features/javascript), the upcoming 8.0-4 release will introduce a similarly positioned high-level library designed specifically for JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you! It is really helpful.

Comment: @Tia If this answered your question, please click the button to accept it -- that helps us keep track of which questions still need responses. Thanks!