# What works best when building a search application: search:search or cts:search?

Tags: javascript, xquery, marklogic

I want to know that in order to make a dynamic search application which looks through all the collections and gives the users the ability to use facets, collection facets, pagination, sorting etc what should be the right approach?

I found two functions for this: `search:search`, and `cts:search`. Which matches my needs best?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382898/searchsearch-vs-ctssearch-in-marklogic

Comment: Also https://developer.marklogic.com/pipermail/general/2011-March/007214.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`search:search` is built on top of `cts:search` (as well as other APIs). They’re designed to work together. You should start with `search:search`, though. It is designed specifically for your faceted search use case and includes many conveniences and best practices that might not be obvious with the lower-level APIs, for example, concurrent facet resolution and pagination. If you need to do something more sophisticated than what `search:search` provides out-of-the-box, you can call out to other libraries.

Comment: If you're working in Server-Side JavaScript, you might want to consider JSearch, which provides helpers for cts.search